# working with pointers struct automatically updated

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a product sales management program where I have a structure for storing product data, another to store customer data and another to store sales data. When I insert a new sale has to be associated with a existing product serial number and the id of a existing customer. How do I guarantee when data products and customers struct are changed the sales struct is updated?

Here's what I have:

```
typedef struct{

char serialnumber[10]
char description[100]
float price
}stproducts;

typedef struct{
int id;
char name[50]
char adress[100]
int phonenumber
}stcustomers;

typedef struct{
int idcustomersale;
char serialnumberproductsale[10]
float endprice;
}stsales;


int main()
{
   stproducts pr[1000];
   int countproducts =0;
   stcustomers cust[500];
   int countcustomers=0; 
   stsales sal[1000];
   int countsales=0;

}
```

part of the function insert sale:

```
void insertsale(stsales sal[], int *countsales, stproduct pr[], int countproduct,stcustomers cust[], int countcustomers)
{
char psale[10];
int number;

 consultproducts(pr, countproducts);
 consultcustomers(cust,countcustomers);
 printf("insert the product serial number of the sale:");
 fgets(psale, sizeof psale, stdin);
 strcpy(sal[*countsales].serialnumberproductsale,psale);
 printf("insert the customer id of the sale:");
 scanf ("%d", &number);
 sal[*countsales].idcustomersale=number;

//....................


}
```

For example let's imagine that the id field is changed on the customer struct, automatically the customer id associated with the sale (idcustomersale) must also be updated.

Comment: you avoid repeating/copying information around. Make the `stsales` point to the other structures. Exaclty like a foreign key in a relational DB

Comment: ok thanks. But how i do that!!!! that  is my doubt...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple and it is a fundamental principle independent of the language you use: **avoid repeating/copying information around**.

Make the `sale` refer to the other objects (i.e. product and customer). Exactly like you'd do in a relational DB, using foreign keys.

Assuming each sale is made of a single product:

```
typedef struct {
    stcustomers* customer;
    stproducts* product;
} stsales;
```

So, let's say the sales are kept in a static array

of sales instances, like you have done

```
unsigned int n=0; // the count of sales reached at that point in time
stsales sal[MAXSALES];
stsales *p;
...
p = &sal[n++];
```

or of pointers and they are allocated on demand

```
stsales *sal[MAXSALES];
p = malloc(sizeof(stsales)); // no error checking, just a demo!
sal[n++] = p;
```

In both cases you can then access the fields you had copied over (and any other field) with

```
p->customer->id;
p->product->serialnumber;
```

I recommend to manage your data structures (for the sales and the other objects) via [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

So, assuming `sal` and `n` are global variables (i.e. declared outside `main`, not a very good design practice, but it will do for now), the `insertsale` function could become

```
stsales *insertsale(stcustomers* customer, stproducts* product) {
    p = malloc(sizeof(stsales)); // no error checking, just a demo!
    if (p != NULL) {
        sal[n++] = p;
        p->customer = customer;
        p->product = product;
    }
    return(p);
}
```

Of course, the sales instances should be freed if/when deleted. I leave the exercise to find out how up to you. :)

Comment: It is a C program, so in the struct i have to change to that:

Comment: thank you Pynchia. So i have to put: stsales *allsales[MAXSALES];
p = malloc(sizeof(stsales)); // no error checking, just a demo!
allsales[n++] = p; inside of function insertsale right? and p->idcustomersale->id;
p->serialnumberproductsale->serialnumber; to? Please help i will be very grateful!!!

Comment: that's right. I hope I gave you the right hint. I recommend to study [pointers](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) in depth and memory allocation to clarify things. As my professor used to say: C without pointers is pointless.

Comment: i will make this changes if i have another doubt you will be here? many thanks!!!!

Comment: sorry another doubt!!! how i do declare function insert vendas with this changes?

Comment: see my edited answer now. Pardon me, the attributes of the sale were named wrongly. now it's clearer.